# git connect my local branch with remote

Tags: git

In my local repo if I execute

```
$git branch --all
```

it returns

```
* master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
```

that means that I have a local branch named repo
and 2 remote branches.

If I do

```
$git checkout -b develop
```

it will create a local branch that is unrelated 
to remote branch .

The command

```
$git pull origin develop
```

it will connect my local branch with remote branch?

Comment: No, it means you have a local branched named `master` and two remote branches (assuming you have a remote named `remotes`, if you don't then you actually have 3 local branches, none of which are named `repo`). Where did you get the name `repo` from?

Comment: As for that last command, did you try it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If by "connect" you mean you want your local branch to track the remote branch, then you need to have your branch `--set-upstream-to`. Change to the branch you want to connect and perform

```
git branch --set-upstream-to remotes/origin/develop
```

Then things like `git pull` and `git status` will know which remote branch to track.

Comment: `--set-upstream` is not supported anymore in newer git versions

Comment: And it seems that one way to do it would be: `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master` while checked out to that branch. And make sure that you have that remote branch fetched locally beforehand: `git fetch origin master`

Comment: I believe another way to do it would be to switch to the local develop branch and `git push -u origin develop`

Answer (score 7):

The answer in accepted answer is changed and the updated step `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master` did not work for me. (see **Footnote** below for error)

**Solution**: Below is what made it possible for me to track the develop branch.

**Step 1**: Check your branches (local and remotes using --all option).

```
D:\poseidon>git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
```

So currently there is only one local branch (master) and two remote branches (master and develop).

**Step 2**: From this checked out master branch (and without creating a local develop branch); run below command.

```
D:\poseidon>git branch --track develop remotes/origin/develop
Branch 'develop' set up to track remote branch 'develop' from 'origin'.

D:\poseidon>git branch
  develop
* master

D:\poseidon>git checkout develop
Switched to branch 'develop'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.
```

As you can see the last statement says your local branch develop is up to date with origin develop. You can now pull/push* from this branch.

*Although you may want to push to develop only using PRs and not directly. But it is now tracked and pull/push can be done.

**Footnote**:

```
D:\poseidon>git branch --set-upstream-to develop remotes/origin/develop
fatal: branch 'remotes/origin/develop' does not exist
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do some changes locally and the push it to the branch on the repo, just do:

```
git checkout -b develop origin/develop
```

do some changes

```
git add -A

git commit -m "message, changes was made"

git push -u origin develop origin/develop
```

Git will set up the tracking information during the push.